# Why do I get a reboot instead of a shutdown?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, reboot

After two days of installation, strangely my Ubuntu machine is restarting instead of shutdown from both desktop GUI and command line.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
sudo halt  # (doesn't shutdown, instead freezes on boot screen Plymouth)
```

I had force shutdown by powering off the machine.

This is not happening all the times.

I have been using Ubuntu for 6 months and never experienced this kind of problem.

Comment: Please update your question and tell us what command line shutdown options you have tried and also **in what way** the shutdown does "not work". How do you "*force shutdown*"? Are you able to shutdown using the desktop GUI menu? Please do **not** replay in a comment. Update your question as is recommended in the [faq#howtoask].

Comment: Please see this post.http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: "This is not happening all the times." -> I find that this happens only when the power line is unplugged.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 2 11. I tried the grub options, but they did not change anything. I found out, that I can get the system to shutdown properly when I attach the external mouse that was attached during installation. After removing the mouse the problem reappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue after I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a newly built machine. This answer on [another post](https://askubuntu.com/a/135568/40056) helped me resolve it:

> I resolved by adding acpi=noirq to the kernel arguments

```
sudo editor /etc/default/grub
```

Add

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

Then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with new acer aspre v5 notebook. It has been solved by enabling laptop-mode as running

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

Comment: Its works, for me after installing laptop-mode-tools and running configuration file from dash.

Comment: I have same issue on my Intel NUC, this makes my situation worse, my mouse and keyboard are frozen frequently.

Comment: @KaneBlueriver You can configure that in the settings.

Answer (score 4):

Go into your machines **BIOS** and check for an option called **wake-on-lan** or something similar and **disable it**.

This was what caused this problem on my machine.

Comment: Surprisingly, I found this worked for my case, though I'm not sure why as there should be no WoL packets being sent to the machine.

Comment: On my ASUS BIOS this is option: **ADVANCED** **APM** **Power-On-By-PCI-E** and if I disable that, the shutdown succeeds for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a Wake On Lan motherboard (Gigabyte GA-Z77M-D3H) issue.

My solution:

Install ethtool:

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

Set WOL off:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol d
```

If it works, then edit the `/etc/rc.local` file and add `ethtool -s eth0 wol d`, before the `exit 0` line.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I think my problem is related to the WOL but I need to use this functionality, so I don't want to disable it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same problem on my Acer V5-571G: the laptop shuts down, turns off its power LED, and then starts again after a few seconds. It occurs more often when working on battery.

The problem seems to arise from incorrect work of pm-utils. But if you write `on` into `/sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control`, the kernel takes control over power management at the specified devices - and somehow this makes the hardware to shut down correctly.

So I have written a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  stop) for i in /sys/bus/*/devices/*/power/control ; do echo on > $i ; done 
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

and to make it being executed every time before shutdown I've placed it under name K32power-control-on into /etc/rc0.d directory (don't forget to make the script executable, sudo chmod +x K32power-control-on). After that the laptop shuts down ok.

I think that there are only a few buses/devices which need to have 'on' value written to their power/control, so the list of devices in the script can be restricted, but I just didn't investigate further.

UPD: Here is a more refined solution of the same problem: https://www.behnke.io/fedora-17-on-an-aspire-v5-571-reboot-on-shutdown/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a Thinkpad X230 with Ubuntu 12.04, it always rebooted after shutdown when unplugged. I found the solution described [here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/X230-restarts-when-shutdown/m-p/856605#M4177) to work for me:

Install `laptop-mode-tools` (if it's not already installed):

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

Open grub's config in `/etc/default/grub` in a text editor and add (or change) this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

Update `grub` using the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: :( it didn't worked for me. And even more, my wifi, lcd brightness and other functions in my laptop stop working.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

- disable internal wlan adapter
- buy usb adapter
- fix shutdown

example:

```
lspci found rt3290 wlan 
rt3290 use rt2800pci module

blacklist rt2800pci
```

edit `blacklist.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the line:

```
blacklist rt2800pci
```

reboot linux

test shutdown :)

install wlan usb adapter
`RT2870/RT3070` work :)

Comment: Why would disabling the wlan fix that the computer doesn't shut down correctly?

Comment: My Ralink RT3290 WIFI card also causes the computer to reboot instead of shutting down, but if the card is put in airplane mode then shutdown works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Gigabyte H87N-WIFI) I disabled XHCI in BIOS - so I can still use WOL. I suspect a problem with the xhci_hcd kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

Don't follow the recommendation that says to set

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"

unless you know how to repair a broken Ubuntu system!

It seems that

sudo shutdown -P now

works every time! Note -P not -h

Comment: `shutdown -P now` does not work for me: it simply reboots my machines immediately after shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

For me I thought it was rebooting but it was just asking to decrypt so it can install updates before turning off.  I could not even force it to shutdown - got lucky there :)