# 12.04 rebooting instead of shutting down

Tags: 12.04, server, shutdown

Since I installed my brand new Ubuntu Server 12.04 it keeps rebooting every time I try to power it off. It shuts down and after 3-4 seconds it boots again. I also tried `sudo shutdown -hP now` and searched for similar posts but the [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132882/why-do-i-get-a-reboot-instead-of-a-shutdown) didn't help. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you power off the machine? Pull the power cable? If, so does it come on its self or do you have to press the power button? If so, the first thing I would think of is a hardware issue. Power button, maybe reset button. You can try `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools` to enable laptop mode. or have a look at this page <a>https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair</a>

Comment: Did, for some obseen reason, you push `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Delete` while it was shutting down (showing the Ubuntu logo + the four dots?

Comment: Does `sudo shutdown -h now` work?

Comment: @BiggJJ: I switch off the extension cable within those 3-4 seconds when the machine is powered off.

Comment: @RPi Awesomeness: No.

Comment: @fedorqui Nope.

Comment: Today something strange happened. I had to switch the CPU fans and deactivated wake-on-LAN in BIOS and since then the server shuts down properly. Although the problem is gone, I will still leave the question open for folks with the same problem.