# Restart instead of shutdown after suspend

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, lenovo, reboot

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad T530. I noticed that if I suspend the laptop at some point, the next shutdown will instead cause a restart.

It seems that [I am not alone with this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132882/why-do-i-get-a-reboot-instead-of-a-shutdown) (and many other questions), and I tried most solutions I could find, but nothing worked.

So far the best (or only) working solution was to boot with `acpi=noirq`. This fixes the issue, but then suspending the laptop doesn't lock it. There may be other side-effects which I haven't found as I don't understand the implications of this kernel parameter.

What does `acpi=noirq` do, exactly? How can I lock the computer on suspend? Is there another solution?

Things I have tried:

- `sudo ethtool -s eth0 wtol d` (no effect)
- `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools` (doesn't shut down correctly anymore at all)
- Deactivating "Wake On LAN" in my BIOS (no effect)
- Try to shut down with `sudo shutdown now` and similar (no effect)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead it near common to all Linux

> > sudo init 1 (restart)
> >
> > sudo init 0 (shutdown)

Comment: This isn't really a fix, it's a somewhat questionable workaround for me (if it even works – I haven't tried it). I'd rather try to fix the actual issue.