# Ubuntu 14.04 won't shut down, reboots instead (on Asrock)

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, reboot, acpi

I've researched on this topic and tried all of the recommendations such as editing kernel options `acpi=off`, `acpi=noirq`, `acpi=force`, then `sudo update-grub`. I also disabled wake on lan in the BIOS. Unfortunately, nothing works.

- `/`(root) is mounted to a 256 SSD
- `/home` is mounted to a 1TB HDD
- Asrock Z97 pro4 motherboard
- Intel i7-4790k

Comment: Please check the below link as it was posted earlier also > http://askubuntu.com/questions/132882/why-do-i-get-a-reboot-instead-of-a-shutdown

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66171#c111) I found out that BIOS settings cause this behaviour. It says there that you should enable keyboard and mouse power on. Now the reboot on shutdown is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to shut down one or more programs that you had running. I have the same problem with you and i find out that the Psensor was open when i was trying to shut down my pc. When i shut down Psensor the problem was solved.