# 16.04 reboots 4 seconds after shutdown completes (Acer Aspire V5-571P)

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, acer, reboot

My Acer Aspire V5-571P running Ubuntu 16.04 has started rebooting a couple of seconds after shutdown completes.  It seems that this is an issue that keeps cropping up randomly in Ubuntu?

I've tried the 'laptop-mode-tools' install, and that doesn't seem to have affected it, but nothing I've found has explained in sufficient detail what changes need to be made - can anyone expand?

I've tried the edit to `/etc/default/grub`, as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/383298/544376), but that didn't help at all.  In fact it made things worse. The shutdown screen just hung, and on boot, the purple wash was corrupted, and there was a large amount of commandline messages before the OS would fully boot.  I've removed the `acpi=noirq` text from the file.

The BIOS 'Wake-on-LAN' setting is DISABLED.

I've created the script found here: https://www.behnke.io/fedora-17-on-an-aspire-v5-571-reboot-on-shutdown/, but when I run the last update :

```
sudo chkconfig --add haltusbpower
```

I get the response: `sudo: chkconfig: command not found`, and I'm not sure what to make of it....

Does anyone have any more suggestions?

Additional Testing.

It definitely seems to be something to do with the USB ports - or PORT. 1 in particular (which seems very odd).  If this particular port has a usb key of some sort in it, the laptop will shut down.

Preliminary testing seems to show that it doesn't matter what it is - I've tried it with a Logitech Universal Key (for a trackball), and a Sandisk Cruzer Fit (4Gb). Weirdly,  (I need to check this a few more times), but if one of the other 2 USB ports is used, it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I'm stumped.  Happy enough to have an empty key in a port for the time being though to ensure the laptop shuts down fully.

Further comment:

I installed Apache2 today and at the end of the install there were the following warnings:

```
insserv: Script haltusbpower is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for 
script `haltusbpower'
insserv: Script haltusbpower is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for 
script `haltusbpower'
```

I looked up the warning and found [this on softpanorama](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Troubleshooting/script_is_broken_incomplete_lsb_comment.shtml)

Would this have something to do with the haltusbpowerscript not working as intended?

For Reference - if anyone else has this issue, I ended up just living with the issue by keeping a Sandisk Cruzer Fit permanently plugged in.

Comment: If the solutions in other Q&As here didn't work for you, then this isn't a duplicate. Just link to what you've tried so others don't mark it without knowing you've tried those solutions.

Comment: I would recommend making sure you have the latest BIOS update from [ASUS Support](https://www.asus.com/us/support/) (and if you don't, to re-flash your BIOS). This often fixes a lot of mysterious power management issues.

Comment: are you using multiple OS?

Answer (score 1):

After several hours trying to solve this, I was able to find a final solution to my Acer Aspire V5-471.

I have tried everything which I found in internet with no results in Mint 18.2 64 bits (grub options, wake up in bios, wifi configuration, laptop-mode-tools, kernel update, etc, etc). After a searching in usb issue, I just put that in `/etc/rc.local` above the existing line that says `exit 0`:

```
for usb_ports in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb?/power/control; do 
   echo on > $usb_ports
done
```

It did the trick and I finally could shut down my computer!

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, try shutting it down by shutdown command in terminal.
I do the same with my Acer Aspire V5-571p.

Comment: that doesn't work always