# Please help: power off leads to restart--how to shutdown without reboot in 22.04 fresh upgrade?

Tags: 20.04, grub2, shutdown, reboot, 22.04

Would really appreciate help as I am stuck with this problem and am now posting here as I did not get a response to [this question](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474908) on Ubuntu forums.

I upgraded a Dell Precision workstation 3450 that came pre-installed with Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. After the upgrade to 22.04, I am unable to shut down the computer using either the power off option (clicking on the power off/log out button on the top right) or with `sudo poweroff` (`sudo shutdown -P` or `sudo shutdown -h now`). In both cases, the machine simply reboots / restarts. The only way to shutdown is by forcing a shutdown by long-pressing the main power button on the CPU.

When I try to shutdown normally, the following lines flash briefly on the console each time and it reboots:
[ 25.433431] sd-umoun[2594]: Failed to unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy 
[ 25.434705] sd-umoun[2595]: Failed to unmount /oldroot/sys: Device or resource busy 
[ 25.442580] shutdown[1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474908): Failed to finalise file systems, ignoring.

This seems to be similar to a problem [reported long ago for 12.04 here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132882/why-do-i-get-a-reboot-instead-of-a-shutdown). As suggested there, should I edit `sudo editor /etc/default/grub` and change :
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
(have not tried this as I am not sure it is the right fix).

Note: I have Linux kernel 5.14.0-1034-oem #37-Ubuntu SMP and for some reason despite running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt ugprade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, the system has not updated to kernel 5.15.

I would appreciate any help/suggestions on how to fix this asap.

Thanks much, trsr

Comment: If your system is *detected* as benefiting from an OEM kernel at install; the default kernel is replaced. Were you using the OEM kernel before upgrade (*if fully upgraded, a 20.04 system was using 5.4 with the GA kernel stack & 5.13 if using the HWE stack; which were you using? or were you using an OEM kernel stack?*).  OEM kernels upgrade to later OEM kernels by default; so I'd not expect you to upgrade to 5.15 *general* kernel.  If it was me; I'd *boot* live media & see if the issue occurs there, then if different contrast differences with your installed system (esp. kernel stack related)

Answer (score 0):

The problem simply disappeared after I replaced an old USB keyboard and plugged in a new one. The computer now shuts down properly. Putting this out there in case others run into similar issues.

Comment: Well done for solving it.  (*I've experienced like issue(s) before and assumed it was a USB device that was sending bad data.. as scanning input from USB showed lots of repeating rubbish that was mostly ignored.. maybe that slowed/delayed-forever the kernel's shutdown, I don't know*).  Thanks for sharing your finding so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an Asrock Intel Z97 motherboard after inserting an ATEN CS1922 KVM between a Bluetooth keyboard/dongle and a USB 3.0 port on the motherboard. I fixed it by setting Deep Sleep to S5 in UEFI Advanced / Chipset configuration. I was able to keep Wake-On-Lan enabled and operational.