# Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 restarts instead of shutting down

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

To provide some details, I'm using an HP Probook 640 G1. It used to have Windows OS on an HDD, but I changed it for a SSD with Ubuntu 20.04 three weeks ago. Ubuntu has been working fine so far, and I was able to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

Only thing is, it used to shut down for good when Windows was in, but it restarts constantly now that I use my SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 OS. I click on shut down button and the computer will just shut down... and then restart.

Does anyone have a clue why ?

Is it maybe something that has to do with BIOS ?

Thank you

Comment: It possibly can be resolved in (or by using the) BIOS. Although an old post, do any of the options listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132882/why-do-i-get-a-reboot-instead-of-a-shutdown) help at all? Please us know how it turns out. :-)

Comment: I tried 3rd answer which wa marked as the solution. It almost broke my computer when I added those on this grub file. I managed to undo what I added to this file. It did not solve my issue, but right now (i don't know how) i'm able to turn it off. (could be some updates on ubuntu ?). If this problem goes back, I'll (carefully ^^) try the other options listed in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I went in BIOS, and deactivated wake On LAN. It worked, the laptop never rebooted when shut down.

Comment: How did you do it? My HP pavilion 14 laptop BIOS doesn't have any Wake on LAN option

Comment: my HP Probook also doesnt have Wake on LAN option

Comment: I have similar issue for Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell Inspiron 15 5510. Any workaroud for this?