# HP pavilion 14 laptop running ubuntu 22.04 restarts everytime I shut it down

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, shutdown, 23.04

Almost all similar answers like [like this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433851/laptop-with-ubuntu-22-04-restarts-instead-of-shutting-down) say to disbale Wake on LAN option in the BIOS, but I went through all the options in the BIOS and didn't find any similar at all. I even disabled secure boot, but it didn't work.
**Edit**
I updated to 23.04 and that seems to have solved the problem

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Yes! Updating to Ubuntu 23.04 seems to have solved the problem after a few days

Comment: yeah, the update happened automatically at some point and all is good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrading to 23.04 solved the issue for me