# Unable to shutdown Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, shutdown

I just have installed Ubuntu 12.04  64 bits just few days ago, and everything is ok, but just some times when I tray to shutdown the system just freezes for a long time, and I have to force the shutdown with the power button.

Any advise or any way to use the terminal to know what is the problem.

I'm using a Dell with ATI video card, 4GB Ram.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a possible duplicate. You should go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown). And try to see if it solves your problem.

Digvijay

Comment: I have tried that before, but din't work !! Thanks so much !!!!....