# Ubuntu restarts on shutdown/hibernation commands, instead of shutdown

Tags: power-management, shutdown, hibernate, restart

Friends, Whenever I am going to shutdown/hibernate my Ubuntu PC its restarting after completing their process. Mean to say if press shutdown button its shutdown properly and switch off the display but suddenly its restart. Any suggestion?

Comment: This older post might help you out :

[Stuck on reboot and shutdown][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown/135568#135568

Comment: Possibly this guide to install **Tux on Ice** could be solution for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/356289/58470

Comment: What is the behavior if you run this command in the terminal `sudo shutdown -P`?