# Ubuntu 12.04 Precise only reboots does not SHUT-DOWN

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

Okay here's the question:

Ubuntu 12.04 Precise will not shut-down it just Reboots again!

Its as simple as that. I have tried every command out there and not a single one
of these commands works in grub or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or any other method suggested.

1. `sudo shutdown -p now` <-This does not work
2. Type in terminal:

   ```
   sudo -i (to get a root shell, sudo gedit is not recommended)
   gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

   - Change this to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
   - Save the file and close the file.
   - Finally, in terminal: `update-grub`
   - `exit` (to end the root shell) <-This does not work
3. `sudo poweroff` <-This does not work
4. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksudo poweroff` <-This does not work
5. Code:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   --> remove `quiet splash`, then :

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   before trying to shut down again, run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a  <-This does not work
   ```
6. `halt` or `shutdown -h now` <-This does not work
7. `sudo init 0` <-This does not work
8. `acpi=norq` added to grub <-This does not work
9. Typing `shutdown` or `restart` in Dash Home <-This does not work
10. `sudo shutdown -h 0` <-This does not work
11. `sudo halt` <-This does not work
12. sudo shutdown -h 0 <-This does not work

So lets try to figure it out together, lets solve it since no updates are coming in to fix it!

Comment: Ray see this [post](http://askubuntu.com/a/135568/123181). It worked for me. After following the instructions restart your PC.

Comment: Could there be a problem in your bios settings? Something like ubuntu triggering an option similar to: go to last state at loss of power?