# Loading directly to the commandline

Tags: command-line, bash, startup

For a completely unrelated problem, I ran `update-grub` following the instructions in user62644's answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432529/ubuntu-12-04-stuck-at-reboot-restarting-system?noredirect=1#432540). Ever since, the GUI has been loading by default upon boot, and I have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to access the bash shell. I would like the bash shell to load by default upon startup, and just type `startx` whenever I need the GUI. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet text"
```

**This assumes you actually need the acpi=noirq** that was in the linked answer. I can't tell you that, it depends on your hardware. Anyway, once you've done this, refresh `grub`:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And you should now load directly to text.

Comment: Thank you. I've been wondering about the `acpi=noirq` part. Originally, the settings were `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and changing it did not solve the problem it claimed to solve, aka. system hangs upon shutdown (which I solved by using `shutdown -HR`). To make things short, I have no clue whether or not I need `acpi=noirq`...

Comment: @biohazard you probably don't, that is usually suggested to solve some graphics problems. You certainly did not solve your shutdown issues by running `shutdown -r` though, that just reboots. Anyway, the main thing is adding `text`, that should cause you to boot into text mode.

Comment: Sorry, it shut down properly when using `shutdown -HR now` (power actually went off). I actually haven't tried `shutdown -r`. Edited my comment above.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like a link is missing in your post after "More details here:"

Comment: OMG sorry it was `shutdown -HP now`!!! I'm so confused.

Comment: @biohazard yes, sorry, I didn't add a link cause I couldn't find the official docs on this and I forgot to delete the text.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo update-rc.d lightdm remove
```

And you will see desired bash logon shell on startup

To restore:

```
sudo update-rc.d lightdm defaults
```

Comment: Thank you! I hesitated which answer to pick, but I felt that @terdon's answer also took into account the context of the previous instructions I had followed. I will remember your solution in case I encounter this again in the future.