# shutdown gets stuck on splash screen

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my old laptop, Dual boot with Windows XP.

Laptop specs:
Gateway MX6128, 2GB Ram, 32 bit

I am completely NEW to Linux... never used it in my life but giving it a shot.  I know how to pull up the terminal and copy commands from this help page.  That's about it.

I have two problems... 1) I can't see any wireless networks and 2) shutdown and restart do not finish. I'll put the more complicated wireless problem in another question, so lets start with the shutdown problem.

When I select shutdown from the menu bar, it goes to the ubuntu splash screen and just sits there with the 5 dots changing from orange to white.  It never shuts down.  I've left it all night like that and it still doesn't shut down.  I have to hold down the power button to power off.  The problem is identical if I ask it to shut down or restart.

I read in another post about hitting esc to see the messages so I did it and something looks suspicious:

```
could not write bytes: Broken pipe
                                                   [OK]
saned disabled; edit /ect/default/saned
* Checking battery state...
Broadcast message from root@gateway-laptop
          (unknown) at 0:03...

The system is going down for halt NOW!
acpid: exiting
Checking for running unattended-upgrades:
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
* Stopping Network connection manager wicd         [OK]
* Asking all remaining processes to terminate...   [OK]
* Killing all remaining processes...               [fail]
modem-manager[744]:<info>   Caught signal 15, shutting down...

* Deconfiguring network interfaces...              [OK]
* Deactivating swap...                             [OK]
umount: /run/lock: not mounted
umount: /run/shm: not mounted
mount: / is busy
* Will now halt
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stuck on reboot and shutdown](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/505737/ubuntu-14-04-hangs-during-shutdown-sticks-on-plymouth-splash-screen-only-respo/581407#581407

Mine resolved either by itself or by update, however when it was happening to me i was getting the message

```
hub 1-0:1.0: connect-rebounce failed, port 5 disabled
hub 1-0:1.0: connect-rebounce failed, port 6 disabled
```

and the command

```
lsusb
```

froze. I read somewhere this can be related to dirty USB ports feeding back too much info and preventing the computer from killing all proccesses. Try removing all unnecessary USB items and plug a USB device in and out a few times on each port to try to clean it. Or possibly use a vacuum.
Hope this helps.