# Ubuntu doesn't shutdown, just reboots

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I use ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop Hp Pavillion x360 11"

The problem is when I click the shutdown option, both Reboot and Shutdown options apeear, but whichever one I choose, my pc just reboots and I'm back at the GRUB screen.

Comment: To troubleshoot... Does it should down if you issue a shutdown command from the terminal?  Alt + Cntrl + T -> Then run `sudo shutdown -h now`?

Comment: Even whit thar command just reboot after 40 seconds

Comment: see if this works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown/135568#135568