# Ubuntu 14.04 not shut down

Tags: shutdown, reboot

Ubuntu 14.04 not shutdown/reboot on Acer laptop(with UEFI) after clicking by the button. If I type in the console `-sudo shutdown -h now` or `-sudo reboot` I can't shutting down my laptop. I always got this image.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions available here on AU? E.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer, https://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown

Comment: and after changing to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"` Ubuntu not shut down

Comment: after changing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"` Ubuntu shut down, but when I start it again, after loading Ubuntu hangs and I can't shutdown it using `Alt+PrtSc+REIUSB`

Comment: You can do `poweroff` for shutdown.

Comment: It not help, Ubuntu hangs with message "Will now halt"